# VBA Selenium SendKeys Ctrl+C not working on Chrome Browser

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried all options and searched but not found VBA code for Chrome Selenium .

I am trying below code:

Please suggest what is missing in the code.

```
Private keys As New selenium.keys
Private driver As New selenium.ChromeDriver

    Sub A_Scrap_Chrome()
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim keyObj As selenium.keys
    Set keyObj = New selenium.keys

     Const JS_NEW_WINDOW = "window.open(arguments[0], name);"
     myURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Random"
     driver.get myURL
        driver.ExecuteScript JS_NEW_WINDOW, myURL
        driver.SwitchToNextWindow

    driver.SendKeys keyObj.Control & "A" '============ Running till Ctrl+A, Selecting all
    driver.SendKeys keyObj.Control & "C" '========== Trying to copy but not working Ctrl+C.

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you specify in the question how you plan to use the text after copying it?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the regular methods (like `FindElement..`) to parse the web side? I can image that parsing the content copied by Ctrl+C is going to be rather complicated.

Comment: Hi tomasz - I am trying to copy from Chrome web to excel's Sheet1 tab.

Comment: Hi FunThomas - FindElements is not working for span with itemprop. I need title, Price and UPC Code:       <div class="product-summary-title" itemprop="name" id="name">
        California Gold Nutrition, Capsules
    </div>
<div class="price-container">
<span class="price discount special">
<bdi>$12.35</bdi>
</span>
<div data-slot="floating-element" style="display:none; width: 400px;">
<li>UPC Code:   <span itemprop="gtin12">898220009312</span></li>